# React JS: Get Context Data After getting success on API Call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am stuck at getting context data.

I have a context and a component which uses its data.

I need to get the updated data of context's variable on API call success in my component.

so How can I do that ?
Here what I have tried.

context.js

```js
import React, { useState, createContext,useEffect } from 'react';
import {getData} from './actionMethods';

const NewContext = createContext();

function newContextProvider(props) {

 const [dataValue, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMyData = async () => {
            const dataValue  = await getData(); // this is an API call

            setData(dataValue)
        };

        fetchMyData();
    }, []);

     
     return (
        <NewContext.Provider
            value={{
                state: {
                    dataValue
                },
                actions: {
                    
                }
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </NewContext.Provider>
    );
}


const newContextConsumer = newContext.Consumer;

export { newContextProvider, newContextConsumer, newGridContext };
```

myComponent.js

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'

import context from './context'


import deleteAPI from './actionMethods'

function myComponent(props) {

const id= 10

const {state,actions} = useContext(context)
  
  deleteAPI(id).then(res => {
    if (res){
      // what should I write here to get the updated Data from the context which will call an API to get the updated data.    
    }
  })
  
  
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: your context will call only one time, since there is no deps array in useEffect of context. And can you explain the workflow so on componentDidMount you need to call an api and populate that data into your component the api call will happen in context and you need to get that data and render in component. is that what you are looking for

Comment: exactly.. so basically I have 10 list which is stored in Context variable. when I call the delete list API from my component, I should get 9 list (the updated list) data by calling an API on delete API call success. so how can I do that ?

Comment: so i will recollect one more time, initially it will show 10 list and clicking on del button attached to each list it will remove the item from the context and will show 9 list items. So context component will call the data for first time and get 10 items and render 10 items in the child component, clicking on del button it will remove by finding the id from the context and remaining 9 list items will get render. Am i correct !!

Comment: yes.. so basically when a page loads.. the API will be called from context which will fetch the list let say 10. so after deleting 1 list, again an API will be called to get the latest list

Comment: I think alvaro has already given a solution let me know if you need any further on this

Comment: is that possible to compare previous list and current list , so that I don't need to write CRUD operation function in context itself. as I am using context to get the list only. so is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As a generic example, one option is to fetch the data from the server when the app loads in the front-end. From there you can send requests to modify the server data and at the same time update your local version. Something like:

1. Fetch data and save it to the local store: `[{id: 0, name: 'first'},{id: 1, name: 'second'}]`
2. Modify the data sending a request to the server. For example deleting an item. `id: 0`
3. Once the server responds confirming the operation was successful you can modify that data in the local store. `[{id: 1, name: 'second'}]`

You can handle the data using a Redux store or a React Context. For example, using a Context:

```
export const ItemsContext = createContext([]);

export const ItemsContextProvider = props => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const deleteItem = id => {
        deleteItemsAxios(id).then(() => {
            setItems(items => items.filter(item => item.id !== id));
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchItems = async () => {
            const items_fetched = await fetchItemsAxios();

            if (items_fetched) {
                setItems(items_fetched);
            } else {
                // Something went wrong
            }
        };

        fetchItems();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ItemsContext.Provider
            value={{
                items,
                deleteItem
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </ItemsContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

We define a Component that will manage the data fetch. The data items are inside a state. When the Component mounts we fetch the items and save them in the state. If we want to delete an item we first call the corresponding fetch function. Once it finishes, if it was successful, we update the state and remove that item. We use React Context to pass the `items` data, as well as the `deleteItem` function, to any component that needs them.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. can I do that using dep array ? I mean comparing my list in useeffect. if it defers then call the API. like that.

Comment: You are welcome. In this approach the server won't tell you when its data is modified. You would need to modify it and then fetch it again. You could do that but in theory it is not necessary as that second the returned data would be the one you already have. For example: You fetch and save `[item1,item2,item3]`, send a request to remove` item2`, fetch again and receive `[item1,item3]`. This last fetch was unncessary. Am I making it clear?

Comment: is that possible to compare previous list and current list , so that I don't need to write CRUD operation function in context itself. as I am using context to get the list only. so is it possible ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding correctly. Where do you want to have those CRUD operations? How would the list change to have a previous an current one without modyfing it?

Comment: so basically I have my CRUD operation calling API in my component. I show list that I am getting from my context. so whenever I delete any list from my component then I just want to get the latest list from the API that I have used in my context. this is what I want.

Comment: So you would like the server to send back the data when it has been modified? If this is the case, I believe you would need to use something like Web Sockets. But I cant help you there, I have no experience with them.

Comment: no no.. I just want to call API to get the latest list when I delete any list. that's all I want.

Comment: Then you can simply call the same `fetchItems` function inside `deleteItemsAxios`. Basically replicate the `fetchItems` function inside the `.then` callback of `deleteItemsAxios`.