# Object is not iterable while using useContext

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

i'm using useContext to update a counter and everything was working fine until i used it on new component.
Now im getting : Object is not iterable error.

I'm little bit confused because same code is working on other components.

my context :

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext();
export default CartContext;
```

Provider :

```
  const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <CartContext.Provider value={[cartValue, setCartValue]}>
        <Navigation />
        {children}
        <ToastContainer />
      </CartContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
```

Working on x component  :

```
const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useContext(CartContext);
```

Not working same line of code on y compoent :

```
const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useContext(CartContext);
//causing TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Im using context in this componets :
ProductCard

Navigation

Cart -> here not working

Comment: Is `y component` a descendant of `Provider`? It sounds like it might not be, and thus it is seeing the default value, which is `undefined`.

Comment: no it is not but i'm using context in ProductCard component that is also not descendent and it is working fine

Comment: I think you confuse `useContext` with `useState`. I don't think contexts are designed to return arrays but objects, but not sure

Comment: @MaximeHelen they can provide any value you want, including arrays.

Comment: you can't destucture context like that and expect that it works. useContext was meant to return a single value. Destructuring would only work if it returned an array, i.e. if context value was an array

Comment: @DejanJanjušević what do you mean ? look Nicholas Tower answer to Maxime Helen ... is this wrong so : https://dev.to/efearas/how-to-usecontext-and-set-value-of-context-in-child-components-in-3-steps-3j9h ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Looking at closer the problem, I think the main issue comes from the `undefined` default value. Looks like `y` component is consumed before the provider is interpreted

Comment: @MaximeHelen i'll try to solve this and let you know.

Comment: @MaximeHelen any idea how i can solve that issue ?? tried to use useReducer to but same issue undefined value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure why are you getting this specific error, but I'm very very sure that you are using `useContext` in an unintended manner.

If you take a look at the [useContext documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) you can see that it is used only to subscribe the current component to a certain provider.

> useContext(MyContext) only lets you read the context and subscribe to its changes. You still need a <MyContext.Provider> above in the tree to provide the value for this context.

The "react way" of doing this, would be the following:

1. store `cartValue` in the root component (not necessarily app root, but whatever it's "high" enough)
2. pass the `cartValue` stored in the root to the context provider
3. pass the `setCartValue` function to any component that should be able to change the value

The code should be something like that:

```
const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <CartContext.Provider value={cartValue}>
        <Navigation />
           // inside AnyOtherComponent you have to use useContext
           <AnyOtherComponent handleCartChange={setCartValue}/>
        <ToastContainer />
      </CartContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
```

For further reference take a look at [dynamic contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context).

Comment: This is unnecessarily convoluted IMHO. 1. and 3. could be just implemented in the context. Here is a suggestion on how to maintain a list from a context https://stackoverflow.com/a/59372881/2647671